# Can't seem to get a release APK build with Xamarin Business for Android

Tags: android, xamarin, apk

I have worked through the web docs and set all the settings, but when I do a release build this is all I get in bin/Release:

[image: bin/Release]

I wanted to show you the output from the build but its too verbose and Stack overflow wont allow it.

Please ask for any other information that would be helpful.

Comment: Is APK created when u Run Release build ? (i mean Run from Xamarin Studio). It should deploy something, so i suppose it should create APK.

Answer (score 1):

If you looking to just create a package, you can do so via

Project -> Create Package ...

You wont need to select a keystore and will be able to create a .apk file useful for testing.

Answer (score 0):

For creating the APK you need to go to the menu **Project** -> **Publish Android Application**. For completing the APK build you need to create a keystore.

I hope it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the .apk you first have to set the build to Release mode and then click on Project -> Create Android Package...